# Top-level VHDL entity not using any FPGA resources

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl

My top-level VHDL entity is not working as expected. The components themselves were working but when I instantiate them the mapping report shows 0 registers were used. Is there an issue with my code? It uses a JTAG primitive as input to send commands to the decoder entity.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
library machxo2;
use machxo2.components.ALL;


entity top is
    port (
    signals : out std_logic_vector (18 downto 0) := (others => '1')
    );
end top;

architecture struct of top is


    
signal  jtdi :  std_logic;
signal  jtck :  std_logic;
signal  jshift :  std_logic;
signal  jrstn :  std_logic;
signal  jupdate :  std_logic;
signal  jce :  std_logic_vector(2 downto 1);
signal  jtdo :  std_logic_vector(2 downto 1);
signal  jrti :   std_logic_vector(2 downto 1);
signal ready : std_logic;
signal data : std_logic_vector(47 downto 0);
signal jtag2dec  : std_logic;
signal dec2jtag : std_logic;


    
component decoder is
    generic (
        SEED_COMMAND  : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (0 => '1', 7 => '1', others => '0');
        RESET_COMMAND : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (0 => '1', 7 => '1', 1 => '1', others => '0');
        PARAM_COMMAND : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (0 => '1', 7 => '1', 2 => '1', others => '0')
        -- NEXT_COMMAND  : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (0 => '1', 7 => '1', 2 => '1', 1 => '1', others => '0');
        -- WAITING    : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) :=  (0 => '0', 7 => '0', others => '1');
        -- DONE_COMMAND  : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) :=  (0 => '0', 7 => '0', 1 => '0', others => '1')
    );
    port (
        data : in std_logic_vector(47 downto 0) ;
        signals : out std_logic_vector (18 downto 0) := (others => '1');
        -- response : out std_logic_vector (47 downto 0)
        jtag2dec  : in std_logic := '0';
        dec2jtag : out std_logic ;
        ready : out std_logic := '1'
    );
end component;


component jtag_ctrl is
    port  (
    
        jtdi : in std_logic;
        jtck : in std_logic;
        jshift : in std_logic;
        jrstn : in std_logic;
        jupdate : in std_logic;
        jce : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 1);
        jtdo : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 1);
        jrti :  in std_logic_vector(2 downto 1);
        
        dec2jtag : in std_logic;
        jtag2dec : out std_logic := '0';
        ready : in std_logic;
        cmd  :  out std_logic_vector(47 downto 0)
    );

end component;

begin

        
    JTAGF_inst: JTAGF
    generic map (
        ER1 => "ENABLED",
        ER2 => "ENABLED" )
    port map (
        TCK => '0',
        TMS => '0',
        TDI => '0',
        TDO => open,
        --
        JTDI => jtdi,
        JTCK => jtck,
        --
        JSHIFT => jshift,
        JUPDATE => jupdate,
        JRSTN => jrstn,
        --
        JRTI1 => jrti(1),
        JRTI2 => jrti(2),
        --
        JTDO1 => jtdo(1),
        JTDO2 => jtdo(2),
        --
        JCE1 => jce(1),
        JCE2 => jce(2) );
        
    decoderinst : decoder
    generic map (
        SEED_COMMAND  =>  (0 => '1', 7 => '1', others => '0'),
        RESET_COMMAND =>  (0 => '1', 7 => '1', 1 => '1', others => '0'),
        PARAM_COMMAND =>  (0 => '1', 7 => '1', 2 => '1', others => '0')
    )
    port map (
    data => data,
    signals => signals,
    jtag2dec => jtag2dec,
    dec2jtag => dec2jtag,
    ready => ready
    );
    
    
    jtagctrlinst : jtag_ctrl
    port map (
    jtdi => jtdi,
    jtck => jtck,
    jshift => jshift,
    jrstn => jrstn,
    jupdate => jupdate,
    jce => jce,
    jtdo => jtdo,
    jrti => jrti,
    dec2jtag => dec2jtag,
    jtag2dec => jtag2dec,
    ready => ready,
    cmd => data
    );
    
end struct;
```

Comment: So what does this code do? There is no description, comments. Update your question with more details.

Comment: Where is the declaration of `JTAGF`?

Comment: Did the top level entity work in simulation? If not, synthesis has permission to trim out (optimise away) any part that isn't correctly connected to an input or output. That's why you simulate first.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Tony said, your JTAG signals aren't actually connected to anything, so the synthesizer will optimize out the "unused" signals.  Only logic connected to your signal called "signals" will be kept, which all depends what's inside your decoder component.

Answer (score 0):

Your top-level entity does not have any inputs.

All of your circuit is derived from the inputs. So synthesis will produce no logic circuit.

Comment: my inputs are coming from a primitive which I have instantiated in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to dig through some of the synthesis reports to determine if the tools are optimizing away parts of your circuit.  Generally the synthesis report will give some details regarding optimization choices that can sometimes be overridden with certain flags but this is generally considered bad design practice.  It could be something as simple as a single signal not being driven anywhere in the code which has subsequent dependencies that are then optimized away in a type of cascade effect.  As others have suggested you should simulate your design first and see what signals are actually being kept by the synthesis tools and what is being optimized away, these reports exist to help ferret out these issues.